# cpp-neltib (and Boost) default string type in windows

Tags: c++, boost, cpp-netlib

I want to be able to get HTTP request header values that contain utf8 characters in a server built with cpp-netlib. I understand that there are two kind of wrapper classes for requests and responses depending on the used string type - `request_header_narrow` and `request_header_wide`, but while browsing the code to understand how this is actually decided i came down to:

```
template <class Tag>
    struct request_header
    : mpl::if_<
        is_default_string<Tag>,
        request_header_narrow,
        typename mpl::if_<
            is_default_wstring<Tag>,
            request_header_wide,
            unsupported_tag<Tag>
        >::type
    >
    {};
```

and

```
namespace boost { namespace network {

    template <class Tag, class Enable = void>
    struct is_default_string : mpl::false_ {};

    template <class Tag>
    struct is_default_string<Tag, typename enable_if<typename Tag::is_default_string>::type> : mpl::true_ {};

} // namespace network

} // namespace boost
```

and

```
namespace boost { namespace network {

    template <class Tag, class Enable = void>
    struct is_default_wstring : mpl::false_ {};

    template <class Tag>
    struct is_default_wstring<Tag, typename enable_if<typename Tag::is_default_wstring>::type> : mpl::true_ {};

} // namespace network

} // namespace boost
```

Since i'm not too experienced with the template meta programming stuff i did not quite understand the Boosts `mpl::if_` logic and how is the default string type actually determined if both have `mpl::false_` as a default value? Can anyone either clear this or explain how to make cpp-netlib use `std::wstring` as default string type?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found at least one solution, not sure if it's the best so comments are welcome, but seems that at least one way to do this is define a new server tag set an then pass these tags to the server base class:

```
namespace boost { namespace network { namespace http { namespace tags {

    typedef mpl::vector<http, simple, async, pod, default_wstring, server> http_async_wstring_server_tags;

    BOOST_NETWORK_DEFINE_TAG(http_async_wstring_server);

} /* tags */

} /* http */

} /* network */

} /* boost */

namespace http = boost::network::http;
...
typedef http::server_base<http::tags::http_async_wstring_server, CHTTPRequestHandler>::type async_server;
```